# Java - Trigonometry Hell

Tags: java, trigonometry

I have a task of being able to program a Class in Java to calculate the bearing from North to a point. The only objects that are known are 2 positions, both have a bearing from North and the distance from 0. So for example - position 1 - 30 degrees and 10m, position 2 - 190 degrees and 50m. How would you calculate the bearing if you wanted to travel from position 1 to position 2 for instance or from position 2 to 1? I can calculate the distance between the 2 positions using the cosine rule, but have no idea how to create a class that will accuratly calculate the bearing in different scenarios?

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I don't have the lat and lon points, only the initial bearing and distance.

Comment: @LeightonRice Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Applications:

[image]

...once you have all three side lengths, this will give you the third angle of your triangle.

(The Haversine formula is for navigation on a sphere... I think we're just worried about vectors on a plane.)

Comment: Ah, I assumed a sphere because his usage of the word 'North'. Looking at the distances he uses in his example you are probably right.

Comment: What happened to your wikipedia blackout hack? ...In Chrome, you can also hit ESC while the page is loading to stop the sopaOverlay.

Comment: It was blacked out! Haha, I felt it was too out of context to leave in my answer. It was: $("#mw-sopaOverlay").remove(); $("div").show();

Comment: Ha. Nice. I get the feeling Wikipedia intentionally made it *just hard enough* to circumvent so that 90% of users would be blocked, but the savviest 10% (who are mostly anti-SOPA anyway) would be fine.

Comment: This is for a flat plane over small distances.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula, googling it will yield implementations in various languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java version ported from a javascript solution given here:
[Using the Haversine Formula in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript) by talkol

```
// this was a pojo class we used internally...
public class GisPostalCode {

    private String country;
    private String postalCode;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    // getters/setters, etc.
}


public static double distanceBetweenCoordinatesInMiles2(GisPostalCode c1, GisPostalCode c2) {

    double lat2 = c2.getLatitude();
    double lon2 = c2.getLongitude();
    double lat1 = c1.getLatitude();
    double lon1 = c1.getLongitude();

    double R = 6371; // km
    double x1 = lat2 - lat1;
    double dLat = x1 * Math.PI / 180;
    double x2 = lon2 - lon1;
    double dLon = x2 * Math.PI / 180;

    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1*Math.PI/180) * Math.cos(lat2*Math.PI/180) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double d = R * c;

    // convert to miles
    return d / 1.60934;
}
```