# Calculate the distance between two GPRS Coordinates

Tags: javascript, cordova, gprs

I would like to calculate the distance from the values I get from my Cordova-Geolocation Plugin. Is this possible with Javascript? I would like to have the answer in Meters. I'm not able to figure out how this formula works or where to start.

I found many sites which are able to do this, but I'm not able to code this formula on my own. Can someone help me?

Comment: You need some math chops [activated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: Google "havasine formula javascript". Or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)