# How to calculate the distance from 1 location to many other locations in the google maps api?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

Calculate the distance between two points with google maps I have made.
But I want to calculate the interval between two points of the way all other coordinates are. Starting from fixed position, that's my position. So what do I need to do. I feel stupid to ask this question, but look forward to receiving help.

If possible can you give me an example
Thankyou!

Comment: *distance from 1 location to many other locations*: [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) if you are looking for "travel" distance.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the distance between 2 location by using Harverine Formula Here is an answer on how to use that https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561433/9516857

Then you have to get the speed of the vehicle to calculate the time. If you have the speed, by using the distance you calculated you can find how much time you spending as below

```
time = distance / speed
```