# Limiting markers on a mileage radius

Tags: r, leaflet

I have X facilities and Y facilities with their lat/long and I have mapped them with leaflet.  Problem is how can I limit only Ys within say 25miles of X locations?

I have tried serching but not finding much that addresses my issue or at least I don't think does.

```
Z<-leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(lng = Y$longitude, lat = 
  Y$latitude, icon = YIcon, group = "BASE")%>% addMarkers(lng = 
  X$Longitude, lat = X$Latitude, icon = XIcon)
Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something in your question, you just have to measure the distances using https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-distance and create/display the markers only if they match your constraint

Comment: I am having issues because I don't see the syntax used with the distance dunction?  I have the lat and long seperate what is the syntax and how do I use the function?

Comment: It's a method on your map object. Can you give a complete example ?

Comment: The distance function is asking for latlng I have X$Latiture and Y$Latitude as well as their corosponding Longitude I do not see how to use the distance function without code help with syntax on how to use.

Comment: You must have created a map object (var mymap = L.map(...)) ... you use this object to calculate distances: mymap.distance(L.latLng(XLat, XLon), L.latLng(YLat, YLon))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the problem by performing some *spatial operations* before using leaflet. All of the needed functions are in the *sf* library

To ge the Ys facilitities within 25 miles of X facilities you have to:

- Tranform X and Y to a **Projected** projection. Use the st_transform() function.
- Calculate a buffer for X. Let´s say Xbuffer <- st_buufer(X, 40200). The units are in meters.
- Select the Y points in Xbuffer with the st_join() function and a an additional filter. Here you create a new object (Y2).
- Use leaflet to plot X and Y2.

Please notice that a reproducible example could help to give a better answer. 
You may find some additional help in the spatial operations [here](https://orlando-sabogal.github.io/SpatialAnalysis-MontevideoWorkshop2019/Notebooks/WarmUp.nb.html)

Comment: or even a simple haversine formula if you don't want to include an additional library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript)