# Check if point is inside circle

Tags: javascript

I have a GPS Coordinate of a spot called `spotCoordinates` and a center the a circle coordinates `this.state.center` and a radius in kilometers `this.state.radius`

I'm trying to make a method to check if the `spotCoordinates` is inside a circle but I don't know how I can add the radius to the coordinates and how to check if it's actually inside or not. It would be easier if it was a square.

```
 calculateParkingSpotsInTheArea = () => {
      this.state.parkingSpots.map(spot => {
          let spotCoordinates = spot.coordinates;
          console.log(spotCoordinates, this.state.center, this.state.radius);
          // Calculate if the parking spot is inside the circle
      });
  }
```

E.g Values printed in the console `spotCoordinates = [41.5408446218337, -8.612296123028727] center = {lat: 41.536558, lng: -8.627487} radius = 25`

[image]

Any help?

Comment: This thread might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript

Comment: Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the distance from the circle's midpoint.  If it is less than the diameter of the circle, the point is inside.

Comment: @user3783243 it's different. I don't have 2 coordinates. I need to calculate the circle "edges" from the center and radius

Comment: @MikeRobinson You mean "if it is less than the radius ..."

Comment: `41.5408446218337, -8.612296123028727` is one point and `41.536558, lng: -8.627487` is the other, no?

Comment: @user3783243 i tried the haversineDistance method and gives me strange values like `0.0021208675369022113`. How do I know if it's inside or not?

Comment: @user12361681 That is the distance between point 1 and point 2, in miles, so if you want it within the radius divide by 2, so if the return is < 12.5 it is within range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates) SO link and [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

```js
let spotCoordinates1 = [41.5408446218337, -8.612296123028727];
let spotCoordinates2 = [38.817459, -9.282218]

let center = {lat: 41.536558, lng: -8.627487};
let radius = 25

checkIfInside(spotCoordinates1);
checkIfInside(spotCoordinates2);

function checkIfInside(spotCoordinates) {

    let newRadius = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(spotCoordinates[0], spotCoordinates[1], center.lat, center.lng);
    console.log(newRadius)

    if( newRadius < radius ) {
        //point is inside the circle
        console.log('inside')
    }
    else if(newRadius > radius) {
        //point is outside the circle
        console.log('outside')
    }
    else {
        //point is on the circle
        console.log('on the circle')
    }

}

function distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var earthRadiusKm = 6371;

  var dLat = degreesToRadians(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = degreesToRadians(lon2-lon1);

  lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
  lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  return earthRadiusKm * c;
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a coordinate that is outside?

Comment: 38.817459, -9.282218

Comment: kilometerssssss

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the point's distance from the center and see if that is smaller then the radius, here is an example:

```js
const spotCoordinates = {
  lat: 41.5408446218337,
  lng: -8.612296123028727
};
const center = {
  lat: 41.536558,
  lng: -8.627487
};
const radius = 25;


function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var earthRadiusKm = 6371;

  var dLat = degreesToRadians(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = degreesToRadians(lon2-lon1);

  lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
  lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  return earthRadiusKm * c;
}


function isInCircle(latLng) {
  const distance = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(latLng.lat, latLng.lng, center.lat, center.lng);

  const calculationResult = distance <= radius;
  console.log("Is inside", calculationResult);
}

isInCircle(spotCoordinates);
```

And here is an example of this formula in action using Google Maps:
https://jsfiddle.net/dpr9shz3/ to use the demo, just click anywhere on the map and the alert will specify the result of the calculation and whether the circle shape was clicked or not.

Comment: I think this assumes that earth is flat. Nearby spots will not work.

Comment: @user12361681 It will be accurate enough if both the radius and distances are calculated for a flat surface, doing this for a shape like the earth has, it can be quite complex because earth is not a perfect sphere and the calculation will have to take into account how close to the poles the coordinates are.

Comment: @user12361681 I don't see any reason why this will not work for nearby spots.

Comment: It will work for a 3 mile radius then the error starts growing exponentially.

Comment: @user12361681 I've edited my answer and added a fiddle with a demo. The code here assume that the radius is in KM, the one in the demo uses meters.

Comment: @Titus don't you think it's almost the same as my answer?

Comment: @Addis I guess we both got the formula for calculating the distance between two points from the same place.

Answer (score 0):

An expression for this would be:

```
(center.x - pt.x)^2 + (center.y - pt.y)^2 < radius^2
```

You can adjust the comparison operator to check if the pt is on the circle (==) or if it is outside the circle boundary (>).

Here is a JavaScript function that will return -1 if the pt is inside the circle, 0 if it is on the circle and 1 if it is outside the circle.

```js
/**
 * @description Check if a pt is in, on or outside of a circle.
 * @param {[float]} pt The point to test. An array of two floats - x and y coordinates.
 * @param {[float]} center The circle center. An array of two floats - x and y coordinates.
 * @param {float} r The circle radius.
 * @returns {-1 | 0 | 1} -1 if the point is inside, 0 if it is on and 1 if it is outside the circle.
 */
function ptInCircle(pt, center, r) {

    const lhs = Math.pow(center[0] - pt[0], 2) + Math.pow(center[1] - pt[1], 2);
    const rhs = Math.pow(r, 2);

    return lhs < rhs ? -1 : (lhs === rhs ? 0 : 1);
}
```

If you don't like the shorthand nested ternary operator, you can swap the return line for this:

```js
if (lhs < rhs) {
    return -1
} else if (lhs === rhs) {
    return 0
} else {
    return 1
}
```

Usage:

```js
ptInCircle([0, 1], [1, 0], 1)
// Returns 1
```