# how to get multiple nearby locations based on rank using haversine reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, haversine

i'm making an app that can give nearby locations and i'm trying to show some nearby locations. but i can only generate only 1 nearest location. I need at least 5 locations that are closest and sorted by ranking

[What I have tried so far](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lh7tfw?codemirror=1)

[NPM package used to get the distance between locations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-nearest-location)

```
var locations = [......]; // your locations array
var nearestLocations = [];
for (let step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
// check if locations are exhausted


if(locations.length == 0) break;


// get the nearest location


let nearest = findNearestLocation(myLocation, locations);


// push the nearest location


nearestLocations.push(nearest);
console.log(step);
console.log(nearest);



// remove the retrieved location from the locations array


locations = locations.filter(function( location ) {
return (location.lat !== nearest.lat && location.lng !== nearest.lng);
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried so far. And you question is not very complete. Have you implemented the Haversine algorithm on your own or are you using a NPM package? If so what is the package?

Comment: Share your code for more clarity

Comment: @RakibUddin https://codesandbox.io/embed/lh7tfw?codemirror=1

Comment: @Chin.Udara i use npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-nearest-location

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you have provided; the library you are using will only retrieve THE nearest location (only one; the nearest location) out of the locations you specify.

The way I see it; you have two options.

**Option 1:**

You can call the `findNearestLocation` function inside a loop; and remove the nearest location returned from the library from your array of locations.

That way, everytime you call the `findNearestLocation` function, you will eliminate the number of choices in the order of distance (nearest to furthest)

Ex:

```
var locations = [......]; // your locations array
var nearestLocations = [];
for (let step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
  // check if locations are exhausted
  if(locations.length == 0) break;
  // get the nearest location
  let nearest = findNearestLocation(myLocation, locations);
  // push the nearest location
  nearestLocations.push(nearest);
  // remove the retrieved location from the locations array
  locations = locations.filter(function( location ) {
    return (location.lat !== nearest.lat && location.lng !== nearest.lng);
  });
}
// after the loop completes; you can print the array to view the nearest locations.
console.log(nearestLocations);
```

**Option 2:**

If you are using the library to only retrieve the nearest location; you can eliminate the dependency by implementing the Haversine formula yourself. You can refer this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript).

And you can modify the function to return the locations in the order of their distance from your location.

```
// Sort your locations array by distance (nearest to furthest)
var myLocation = // get your current location
locations.sort(function(a, b) {
  let distanceA = haversineDistance(myLocation, a);
  let distanceB = haversineDistance(myLocation, b);
  // Compare the 2 distances
  if (distanceA < distanceB) return -1;
  if (distanceA > distanceB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

The below "haversineDistance" function is extracted from the above link and credit goes to @Nathan Lippi and @talkol.
[Haversine Distance function: original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316500/5321474)

```
function haversineDistance(coords1, coords2, isMiles = false) {
  function toRad(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  var lon1 = coords1[0];
  var lat1 = coords1[1];

  var lon2 = coords2[0];
  var lat2 = coords2[1];

  var R = 6371; // km

  var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
  var dLat = toRad(x1);
  var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
  var dLon = toRad(x2)
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;

  if(isMiles) d /= 1.60934;

  return d;
}
```

Comment: may i get a few examples of the 2nd choice @chin.udara

Comment: I updated my answer with a code example; needless to say you must modify the code to suite your requirement.

Comment: thanks, your answer really helped me. i need to modify a little

Comment: halo @Chin. Udara i get the same locations, how to handle it?

Comment: What do you mean you get the same locations?

Comment: I got the closest location, that's it. can't show at least 5 locations

Comment: You need to update your question with the code you have.

Comment: how to show locations = locations.filter(function( location ) {
    return (location.lat !== nearest.lat && location.lng !== nearest.lng);
  });

Comment: `nearestLocations` array will contain the location in the order. You need to log the array after the for loop.

Comment: I'm still confused

Comment: I updated the answer so that in option 1; it prints the `nearestLocations` array after the loop

Comment: i keep getting the same closest location loop,instead of getting a different location