# How to search nearest location in MongoDB when latitude and longitude are String?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, geolocation

Mistakenly I added the data into my Database's collection in below format

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("6501e33954b107bda89701f5"),
    name: 'M/s Mango Eco Management Pvt. Ltd.',
    address: '348, Folk Industrial Area, Delhi - 002200',
    phone: '+91 1231231231',
    capacity: '1.5 Tonne / Day',
    contact_person: 'Mr. Suman Kumar',
    latitude: '28.538132819961014', 
    longitude: '76.09083529557478'
},
```

**Here latitude and longitude are Strings in DB.**

Below code is for

```
const nearestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    phone: String,
    capacity: String,
    contact_person: String,
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true,
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number], 
        index: '2dsphere', 
      },
    },
  });
const NearestFacility = mongoose.model('nearests', nearestSchema);
```

An Ideal Schema for storing location .

```
app.get('/locations', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.latitude || !req.query.longitude) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing latitude and longitude parameters' });
        return;
    }

    try {
        const latitude = parseFloat(req.query.latitude);
        const longitude = parseFloat(req.query.longitude);

        const nearestFacility = await NearestFacility.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [longitude, latitude], 
                    },
                    distanceField: 'distance',
                    spherical: true,
                },
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    distance: { $lte: 10000 } 
                }
            },
            { $limit: 1 },
        ]);

        console.log('Query Coordinates:', longitude, latitude);
        console.log('Nearest Facility:', nearestFacility);

        if (nearestFacility.length > 0) {
            res.json(nearestFacility[0]);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ error: 'No e-waste facility found near this location' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while searching for the nearest facility' });
    }
});
```

***In above API code provide a possible solution where the aggregate code work for strings type (latitude and longitude).***
Which is String type mistakenly.

```
const nearestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String,
    phone: String,
    capacity: String,
    contact_person: String,
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true,
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number], 
        index: '2dsphere', 
      },
    },
  });
const NearestFacility = mongoose.model('nearests', nearestSchema);
```

When I am providing data in database in this format its working fine.

But here I require to work the on `latitude: String` and `longitude: String`.

Comment: The best option would be to correct your data and update them to a number. `$geoNear` must be the first operation in your pipeline, so you don't have that many choices.

Comment: I respect your solution but is there any other alternate solution like any mathematical calculation or something else ? if not then I have to do this only.

Comment: You could convert the string into numbers and then use the `haversine` function (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript). Be aware, as you cannot create an [geospatial index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-geospatial/#std-label-geospatial-index) you may face serious performance problems in your application. Or check libraries like [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#distance)